# Does Safenet Luna HSM have a function or way to receive one type of cryptogram and return another type of cryptogram?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, hsm

I've a Safenet LUNA HSM in my job and I've been using the "Lunaprovider" Java Cipher to decrypt a RSA cryptogram (getting its plaintext), and then encrypt the plaintext with 3DES algorithm.

We're reviewing what should be the best way to expose an authentication service, so this cryptogram/plaintext is actually a password. Now, we might just go with hashing the password in the frontend, instead of using symmetric encryption. But, I was asking to myself the following:

***Does Safenet LUNA HSM (or LUNA JSP) have a way to set up a function so the HSM can receive, for example, an RSA cryptogram, and return an 3DES cryptogram?***  (so our service will never have the password in clear)

We do not want to have the password in clear in any way or time and we are new  using an HSM product.

Any comment/answer would be great.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safenet HSMs provide a way to write your own cryptographic algorithms for your needs. It is named as Functionality Module(FM). You can write any algorithms without exposing any sensitive data. You can call those codes like other built-in algorithms.

It is embedded software compiled with  GNU Compiler Collection. After compile you have to upload compiled code to HSM. You will need special developers that understand cryptography, HSMs and embedded software. We had a customer that hired a company from Romania that only develops FMs for banks.

> *I have write FMs several times for my company too but its rare to find a specialist.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer man. I will contact safenet support to know about this FM.